# How do I customise telescope-base?

Tags: meteor, telescope

In the open source example http://www.telesc.pe/, how do I remove digest and daily view items from the view menu? Do I need to modify telescope-base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new package to hold your customizations. You can look at [the Telescope documentation](http://www.telesc.pe/docs/), look at existing theme packages such as `base` and `hubble`, or copy and adapt the `telescope-blank` package.

Once you have your new package, you can simply overwrite the `viewNav` menu. For example:

```
viewNav = [
  {
    route: 'posts_top',
    label: 'top'
  },
  {
    route: 'posts_new',
    label: 'new'
  },
  {
    route: 'posts_best',
    label: 'best'
  }
];
```

The daily view is provided by another package, `telescope-daily`, so you'll need to remove it from the app if you don't want to use it:

```
meteor remove telescope-daily
```

(Note that the digest view will also be extracted out as its own package eventually, but right now it's still part of the core)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

Create a `config.js` under `client/` and put the following code inside :

```
while(viewNav.length > 0){
  viewNav.pop();
}

viewNav.push({
  route: 'posts_top',
  label: 'Top'
});
// etc...
```

This will load after `telescope-base` which is responsible for exporting `viewNav` an array used to control which items are inserted in the menu.

Comment: The code is correct, but you should try not to touch any core files when customizing the app, otherwise that will make it harder to merge in new updates in the future.

Comment: Also, if you want to empty `viewNav` couldn't you just do `viewNav = []`?

Comment: Interestingly, exported symbols from packages are not lvalues, meaning they cannot be reassigned like you suggested. Good point about not messing with the core app code and put every modifications in a separate package.

Comment: I just tested it and `viewNav = []` seems to work as far as I can tell?